# Experience with Kruskal-Wallis versus Zero-Inflated Kruskal-Wallis as nonparametric alternative to one-way ANOVA

Tags: r, anova, nonparametric, zero-inflation, kruskal-wallis-test

I have a data set of 1 categorical predictor (4 levels) and one non-negative continuous response variable (listed as "aphidleaf in histogram). The response variable is not count data and the zeros are important. I am interested in comparing the means of the groups, and was planning a one-way ANOVA until I looked at the data.

My response variable is highly zero inflated (see frequency histogram). I have tried many transformations and have decided to use a nonparametric test. Kruskal Wallis will be straightforward and appropriate for my question to determine any difference in response variable between the treatment groups, but I found that there is a zero-inflated Kruskal Wallis test.  Does anyone have any experience with the difference between the two or any to choosing one over the other? https://github.com/chvlyl/ZIR

I know Kruskal Wallis is familiar to many people, so I wonder if it is a more widely accepted approach than the zero-inflated[image: zero-inflated histogram]

Comment: Try the ZI Kruskal Wallis test. paper by Wang, Chen and Li (2021) available on MathArch. the titke is "Rank-Based Tests for Nonnegative Data with
Excessive Zeros with Applications to Microbiome Data". R code available, works well.
Good luck
SH

Answer (score 2):

The solution needn’t be very complicated.  Rank tests can handle extreme numbers of tied values if you are a bit careful in computing p-values.  It is best to use the generalization of the K-W test, which is the proportional odds ordinal logistic semiparametric regression model.  The PO model can handle extreme ties, since it reduces to the binary logistic model if there are only 2 distinct Y values.  See [here](https://fharrell.com/post/rpo) for resources.

Comment: If you run the PO regression on the four-level factor variable, however, then isn’t chunk testing the coefficients equivalent to KW? Even if zero-inflated KW can’t be generalized to a full regression setting like regular KW can, I wonder how the two compare when we are in a simple setting.

Comment: Yes except P-values from likelihood ratio tests using the PO model may be more accurate when there are many ties.  The real question is whether you need to explicitly handle zero inflation.  I doubt it.  If you do, then a Heckman 2-stage model may be worth a look (model Pr(Y=0) then Pr(Y | Y>0) and put them together).